# Select count with join in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I check how many products added by a,b,c,d respectively by using a query?

table1

```
admin_id admin_name
3           a
4           b
5           c  
6           d
```

table2

```
admin_id products
3          pDeal
3          pSeal    
4          pAeal
5          pZeal
6          pXeal    
3          pHeal
6          pPeal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a simple JOIN and a COUNT query:

```
SELECT table1.admin_name, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM
  table1 INNER JOIN table2
  ON table1.admin_id = table2.admin_id
GROUP BY
  table1.admin_name
```

Comment: Rather than INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN will suit best in here, Won't it? ALso GROUPING on the column admin_name might result in a slow query as admin_name won't be indexed(well in most case)!!

Comment: @MaK you could use an `INNER JOIN` with `COUNT(*)` or a `LEFT JOIN` with `COUNT(table2.admin_id)`, the left join will return all admins even those with 0 products, the inner join only those that have at least 1 product

Comment: Thanks a tone fthiella

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
    SELECT a.admin_name, COUNT(b.products) as 'CountOfProducts' 
    FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.admin_id = b.admin_id
    GROUP BY a.admin_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
SELECT adm.admin_name,COUNT(pdr.products) as ProductCnt 
FROM table1 AS adm 
JOIN table2 AS pdr 
  ON adm.admin_id = pdr.admin_id 
GROUP BY adm.admin_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.admin_name, COUNT(t2.products)
FROM table1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.admin_id = t2.admin_id
WHERE 1
GROUP BY t2.admin_id
```

The LEFT JOIN will ensure the cases when table2 doesn't have any record for some admin of table 1.

Comment: @shA.t I don't think it'll. Check out this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c086/2

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inner-select like this:

```
SELECT 
    table1.admin_name, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM table2 
     WHERE table1.admin_id = table2.admin_id) As cnt
FROM
  table1;
```